# External Access To Calendars

Tags: sharepoint, exchange, exchange-2003, outlook, calendar

As a very diverse and technical bunch I thought I would ask the question here and see how people do things.

We have a requirement for people outside of our organisation / network / domain to view internal people's calendars for the purposes of booking meetings.

How do people in other places deal with this?

We are running XP / Office 2003 / Win 2003 domain / Exchange 2003

Can this be done with Sharepoint?

Any other clever ways to do it?

Look forward to your input.

regards

Kip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done with Sharepoint, assuming you have made it available to the outside world already.

Or, you could sync your internal Calendars with something external, such as Google Calendar, which can be shared selectively.

Comment: I think sharepoint may be the way to go. Due to the organisation we could never commit to google etc.#

Thanks